# Kafka Topology Design: How to do sliding window join and emit events on timeout? [Hard]

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, confluent-platform, ktable

I have a set of requirements as below:

1. Message 'T' arrives, must wait for 5 seconds for corresponding message in 'A' to arrive (with same key). If it comes within 5 seconds, then send joined values and send downstream. If it does not come within 5 seconds, send only 'T' message downstream.
2. Message 'A' arrives, must wait for 5 seconds for corresponding message in 'T' to arrive (with same key). If it comes within 5 seconds, then send joined values and send downstream. If it does not come within 5 seconds, send only 'A' message downstream.

[image]

My current thinking was to do a KStream-KStream Sliding Window OUTER join. However, that does not wait for 5 seconds before sending the (T, null) or (null, T) message downstream (that is done instantly).

I need to wait for a timeout to happen, and if a join did not occur, then send the unjoined message through.

I've attached a diagram to help make sense of the cases. I am trying to use DSL as much as possible.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I found a fairly hacky solution that i'm still evaluating, but will work for this scenario.

I can simply groupByKey at the end and then suppress until window expires, with an unbounded buffer.

Comment: Interesting solution... How do you set the window size for the aggregation? Note, that `TimeWindows` are aligned to the epoch, ie, if you set window size 5sec, you get windows from `[0,5),[5,10)` etc. Thus, if T has timestamp 3, the window would end already 2 seconds later (not 5 seconds later). Furthermore, it seems that it might only work if you know that there won't be a second message on the same input topic with the same key within the timeout: if there could be a T2 after T1 before the T1 timeout expires, T2 would overwrite T1 (well, I guess it depends how you define your `aggregate()`).

Comment: Bottom line: Kafka Streams should change the semantics of `outerJoin()` and not emit eagerly. -- To build a custom solution, you might want to do the join completely manually. Using punctuation might be useful (even if not strictly necessary to use).

Comment: For the record, @MatthiasJ.Sax 's concern has been addressed and is tagged as "Fix Version 3.1.0", i.e. a future release (currently, we are at 3.0.0-rc2), here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-10847

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky Could you give an example of how to do it after the issue was addressed?